# Increment by 1 to work for all shells

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, osx

I am using `expr` to incremement a number that comes from a file.
Although the following works:

```
NUM=$(expr $(grep customer file.txt | cut -f4 -d' ' | sort -n | tail -n 1) + 1)
```

I am not sure if `expr` is available in all shells.
But the following does not work:

```
NUM=$((grep customer file.txt | cut -f4 -d' ' | sort -n | tail -n 1) + 1))
```

So is there a way to do the increment by one in a way that works for all shells?

Comment: You mean all shells, not distros, right?

Comment: @Sparhawk:Yes that's right

Comment: @Jim : `expr` is not a shell command, so it doesn't make sense to ask whether it is available in all shells. You might ask whether `expr` is available in all operating systems, but this is a different story.

Comment: @Jim : If you ask about a solution to work *for all shells*, please be explain what you mean by this. I guess you do not look for something which works the same way in tcsh, ksh and fish, do you?

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the largest number in column 4 on lines containing the word `customer`, and assign this plus one to `NUM`:

```
 NUM=$( awk '/customer/ && $4 > n { n = $4 } END { print n + 1 }' file.txt )
```

`expr` would work in any POSIX shell (it's not dependent on what distribution of Linux you use, really).

So would

```
NUM=$(( $( grep ... ) + 1 ))
```

but you are using

```
NUM=$(( grep ... ) + 1 ))
```

which has unbalanced parentheses.

I would go with the simpler `awk` variation though.

Comment: So how do I know that the shell is POSIX? Does it depend on the she-bang? Would it work in all MACs or would `expr` need to be installed?

Comment: @Jim You can safely rely on `expr` being available, and you can safely rely on `$(( ... ))` working in any POSIX shell on a modern (not decades-old) Unix.  `sh` will be a POSIX shell, as would `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh` be (but with further extensions), if they are installed.